# Javascript alert is not working in Update Panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I am working on asp.net web application.
I have one UpdatePanel and there is table inside table which has data in some TextBoxes.

I have one save button too inside this UpdatePanel
So I want to save this data into Database, when I click Save Button.

This is working fine till now.

But I want to show alert message to User that information saved successfully. I'm using javascript for this purpose, But Javascript is not working. 
so is this possible to achieve the desired functionality using javascript, if yes then please guide me Or if there is any other alternative method except this please let me know.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have update panel use **ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock** as below

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Member Registered Sucessfully');", true)
```

Remember that you can't use Response.Write during an asynchronous postback.

It would be good if you have posted your code here.

Comment: can i have like dynamic name of member rather than jst memeber.
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Member Registered Sucessfully');", true)

Comment: @Monika your fix worked for me.  You asked to see the original poster's code, FYI this is what I was calling previously: Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(  and this is what I changed that to (in VB): ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock( Page,

Answer (score 1):

Try This Line of Code 
Its Definitely work with Update panel.

```
var message = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("Bill No. : " + BillNo + " successfully generated.");
            var script = string.Format("alert({0});window.location ='ChhallanPrint.aspx';", message);
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "", script, true);
```

Comment: its simply for show message and redirect to another page if you want to show message only then you can remove portion of " window.location ='ChhallanPrint.aspx'; " message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for popup sweetalert in asp vb.net

```vb
Dim message As String = " swal('Added!','Country Added Successfully.', 'success')"

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(TryCast(sender, Control), Me.GetType(), "sweetAlert", message, True)
```

Comment: This question is not about vb.net

Answer (score -1):

```
  string message = " swal('"+gelen[2]+"!','Sepete Eklendi.', 'success')";
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(), "sweetAlert", message, true);
```

Comment: Provide an explanation why your code  is preferred to use compared to that of the other three posters. It prevents further downvoting and possible removal of answer.